# Docker EACCES error install bunyan dependency globally

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I am attempting this Docker command:

```
FROM node:9
RUN npm install -g bunyan
```

I am getting this error:

```
gyp WARN EACCES user "nobody" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bunyan/node_modules/dtrace-provider/.node-gyp/9.4.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bunyan/node_modules/dtrace-provider/.node-gyp"
```

I tried using chown:

```
RUN sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/lib
RUN sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/lib/node_modules
RUN sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/bin
RUN sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/share
```

but using chown didn't make a difference.

Anyone know what this error is about?

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, try this:

```
     FROM node:9
     RUN npm install bunyan
```

You will get some warning messages, but it will install it anyways.